# Restrict zip codes for Cash on delivery payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

we restricted only some zip codes for default COD payment method by adding below code in `cashondelivery.php`
:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cashondelivery.php

public function isAvailable($quote = null)
{
if ($quote) {

// Here is the list of restricted Zip Codes
$restrictedZips = array(
'641004'
,'641006'
);

$address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
$customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
if (!in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
return false;
}
}

return parent::isAvailable($quote);
}
```

Now we are using custom COD & we are using following code :

```
public function isAvailable($quote = null)
    {
        if($quote && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal()<Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/max_order_total') && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal()>Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/max_order_total')) {
            return false;
        }
        $specificcountry = explode(",",Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/specificcountry'));
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/allowspecific')!=0 ){
            if(!in_array($quote->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),$specificcountry)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        $cod_charges = Mage::getModel('mpcashondelivery/pricerules')->getAppliedPriceRules();
        if($cod_charges['error']){            
            return false;
        }
        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
```

**How to restrict only some zip codes for this custom COD ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add code like below will work for you

```
if($quote && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal()<Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/max_order_total') && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal()>Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/max_order_total')) {
            return false;
        }
        $specificcountry = explode(",",Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/specificcountry'));
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/allowspecific')!=0 ){
            if(!in_array($quote->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),$specificcountry)){
                return false;
            }
        }
         $cod_charges = Mage::getModel('mpcashondelivery/pricerules')->getAppliedPriceRules();
        if($cod_charges['error']){            
            return false;
        }
       $restrictedZips = array(
           '641004'
          ,'641006'
             );

         $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
          $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
      if (!in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
         return false;
       }
        }
```

Comment: working fine, Now it restricted for all zip codes, but i need to allow for zip codes i entered in above code, i tried with "641004", for this also its not showing COD.

Comment: you want to show for restricted zipcode `$restrictedZips = array(
'641004'
,'641006'
);` check this remove it from here then check

Comment: Thansk for your support bro....

Answer (score 4):

At magento,if you  return value as  false `(return false;)` from  `isAvailable()` from a payment method class  then  `that  payment gateway becomes not available for current checkout`.

So if you add your code at start of ***isAvailable()***, then will works for you.

```
public function isAvailable($quote = null)
    {
    if($quote){
        $restrictedZips = array(
        '641004'
        ,'641006'
        );

    $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
        if (!in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
            return false;
            }
        }
        /* add rest of code  */
        *****       
    }
```

Comment: Thansk a lot, i just got  an answer.....

Comment: i checked this one, its working fine.

Comment: you are awesome , after i got an answer also you are editing answer to help other users.

Comment: At observer function change $event to $observer

Comment: thanks for helping me here, please look at my other questions